# probability of 4 couples sitting opposite to each other at a round table with 8 seats

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

After all are seated, I though I can look at four of them. There is a $1/8$ probability of the first person sitting in front of its mate, then $1/7$ for the second, $1/6$ for the third and $1/5$ for the fourth. Yet I'm sure there is still something missing. Should I multiply it by the permutations of each couple? I feel lost at these kinds of questions, I will be glad to hear how does one get to solve them.

Comment: Does "sitting in front" mean "adjacent" or "opposite"?

Comment: opposite, I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the chairs$\;1,...,8\;$in clockwise order.

There are $4$ pairs of opposite chairs, namely $(1,5),(2,6),(3,7),(4,8)$.

- For the first couple (couple #$1$), there are $4$ choices for their pair of opposite chairs, and then $2$ ways for the couple to choose their seats.$\\[4pt]$

  For the next couple (couple #$2$), there are $3$ choices for their pair of opposite chairs, and then $2$ ways for the couple to choose their seats.$\\[4pt]$

  For the next couple (couple #$3$), there are $2$ choices for their pair of opposite chairs, and then $2$ ways for the couple to choose their seats.$\\[4pt]$

  For the last couple (couple #$4$), there is only $1$ choice for their pair of opposite chairs, and then $2$ ways for the couple to choose their seats.$\\[4pt]$

hence there are
$$
(4{\,\cdot\,}2)
(3{\,\cdot\,}2)
(2{\,\cdot\,}2)
(1{\,\cdot\,}2)
=2^4{\,\cdot\,}4!
$$
acceptable seatings out of $8!$ possible seatings.

Thus the probability of an acceptable seating is
$$
\frac{2^4{\,\cdot\,}4!}{8!}=\frac{1}{105}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By convention, in a circular permutation, only the relative order of the people matters.  Therefore, we can consider seating arrangements relative to one of the people at the table.

Suppose Julia is one of the eight people.  Seat her.  We will use her as our reference point.  There are $7!$ ways to seat the remaining seven people as we proceed clockwise around the table from Julia.

For the favorable cases, we again begin by seating Julia.  Her mate can be seated opposite to her in one way.  That leaves six people who could be seated to Julia's immediate left.  That person's mate must be seated to the immediate left of Julia's mate.  That leaves four people who could be seated two seats to Julia's left.  That person's mate must be seated two seats to the left of Julia's mate.  That leaves two people who could be seated to Julia's immediate right.  That person's mate must be seated to the immediate right of Julia's mate.  Hence, there are
$$6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2$$
favorable seating arrangements.

Hence, the probability that if the members of four couples are seated randomly at a round table that each person sits opposite to his or her mate is
$$\frac{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{7!} = \frac{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2}{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{1}{7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1} = \frac{1}{105}$$

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, imagine the round table to be the unit circle. It is clear that we have $4$ seats, $2$ each on $x$- and $y$- axes, and $2$ each along $y=x$ and $x+y=0$. Let us consider the $4$ adjacent seats, $(0,1), (\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}, \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}), (1,0), (\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}, -\frac {1}{\sqrt 2})$. We can seat $1$ member of each couple here, either the male or the female, and then we can fix the other member to sit opposite to her spouse. There are $(\binom 21)^4$ ways to choose one member of each couple, and then there are $4!$ ways to seat them. Once these are seated, the rest of the arrangement is fixed. Note that we must divide by $8$ afterwards, because although we have marked coordinate axes for this solution, in reality there are none, and hence we have $8$ possible starting positions (for example, here we took starting point to be $(0,1)$).
This gives us the total number of favorable cases, as $48$.

Total possible cases is, of course, $\frac {8!}{8}=7!$. Hence probability comes out to be:
$$P=\frac {48}{5040}=\frac {1}{105}$$

Answer (score 0):

Same thing, possibly shortest expression, $\frac{8!!}{8!} = \frac1{105}$

(Ladies sit 1 by 1 in available seats, reserving opposite end for spouse)